# Pass variable function arguments on to another function in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to pass variable function arguments to one function, `foo`, and then have `foo` pass the variable function arguments on to another function, `bar`.

At the same time, the initial caller should also be able to call `bar` directly with variable function arguments.

How can I do this, since `$args` is converted to an array when it reaches `foo` and thus can't be passed on as variable function arguments?

```
function bar($prefix, ...$args) {
  foreach($args as $arg)
    echo "bar: $prefix: $arg\n";
}

function foo($prefix, ...$args) {
  echo "Just passing through...\n";
  foreach($args as $arg)
    echo "foo: $prefix: $arg\n";
  bar($prefix, $args); // wrong, since $args is now an array
}

foo("Idefix", "FOO", "BAR");
bar("Obelix", "ABC", "DEF");
```

Comment: I do not agree. First, the question I linked was answered 2 years ago, with better quality answers. When future novice developers will search for an answer to this question they should stumble upon that question. Secondly, it is not about the context, but rather the clarity of the question and its answers. The context may make sense to you, but would other people also benefit from it? If you really do have something of value to add you can post a comment on the old question, but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the call to `bar` in `foo` to use [variable arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) too. That spreads `$args` back out into individual parameters, which are then consolidated back into an array inside `bar`.

```
function bar($prefix, ...$args) {
  foreach($args as $arg)
    echo "bar: $prefix: $arg\n";
}
function foo($prefix, ...$args) {
  echo "Just passing through...\n";
  foreach($args as $arg)
    echo "foo: $prefix: $arg\n";
  bar($prefix, ...$args);
}

foo("Idefix", "FOO", "BAR");
bar("Obelix", "ABC", "DEF");
```

Output:

```
Just passing through...
foo: Idefix: FOO
foo: Idefix: BAR
bar: Idefix: FOO
bar: Idefix: BAR
bar: Obelix: ABC
bar: Obelix: DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

if bar() don't use array the you should pass `$arg` and not `$args`

```
  function foo($prefix, ...$args) {
    echo "Just passing through...\n";
    foreach($args as $arg)
      echo "foo: $prefix: $arg\n";
    bar($prefix, $arg); 
  }
```